# Help with Implementation of binary search for names in an array of structs

Tags: c++, search, cstring

I need to use a binary search to find a requested name in an array of structs. I used a binary search example code that searched ints and modified it to search through the array indecies to compare the names in each struct. The program runs but the name is never found so something is definitely going wrong somewhere. Not sure if it is the way I am taking in the name from the stream or just my implementation of the search in general. Can anyone take a look provide some feed back? thanks

**relevent code from the input function:**

```
char entryName[31];
char discard;
string entryNameString;

cout << "What is the name of the entry you would like to look up?" << endl;
cin >> entryNameString;
cin.get(entryName, 30);
cin.get(discard);
findName(listLength, arrayOfStructs, entryName);
```

**the binary search function:**

```
void findName(int listLength, contactInfo* arrayOfStructs, const char* entryName)
{
    bool found = false;
    int low = 0, high = listLength-1, mid;

    while (!found && low <= high)
    {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (strcmp(entryName, arrayOfStructs[mid].contactName) == 0)
            found = true;
        else
           if (strcmp(entryName, arrayOfStructs[mid].contactName) < 0)
              high = mid - 1;
           else
              low = mid + 1;
    }

    if (found)
    {
        cout << arrayOfStructs[mid].contactName << endl;
        cout << arrayOfStructs[mid].birthday << endl;
        cout << arrayOfStructs[mid].addressInfo.streetName << endl;
        cout << arrayOfStructs[mid].addressInfo.cityName << endl;
        cout << arrayOfStructs[mid].addressInfo.state << " ";
        cout << arrayOfStructs[mid].addressInfo.zipcode << " ";
        cout << arrayOfStructs[mid].addressInfo.phoneNumber << endl;
        cout << arrayOfStructs[mid].typeOfentry << endl;
    }
    else
       cout << "NOT FOUND" << endl;
}
```

EDIT: arrayOfstructs[].contactName is ordered alphabetically, (e.g. .contactName = Amanda, is located in a smaller index than .contactName = Zorak)

Comment: Is the exercise here to write your own binary search?  If not, then you can just use `std::find`.

Comment: Your array is sorted by contactName right?

Comment: @benjamin Probably should have mentioned the array is sorted alphabetically based on the contact name, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you try to enter names separated by whitespace you need to use [`std::getline`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/getline) instead of `istream::operator>>`.

Comment: Thanks, replacing cin >> entryNameString; with getline( cin, entryNameString); fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Since you also asked for general feedback.  Notice that your are potentially comparing the same strings twice for each iteration.  strcmp returns whether its less, equal or greater (-1,0,1).  You could get the return value and perform all futher comparisons with that...

```
int result = strcmp(entryName, arrayOfStructs[mid].contactName);
if (result == 0)            
   found = true;        
else           
  if (result < 0)              
    high = mid - 1;           
  else              
    low = mid + 1;
```